# Haskell get every second line from text file

Tags: haskell, io

I'm new to haskell. I'm trying to read every second line from file for example here's my text file

```
5
1 4 8 6 8
5
2 4 7 9 2
0
```

So result should be

```
1 4 8 6 8
2 4 7 9 2
```

Here how my code looks like

```
import System.IO  
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import Data.Function
import Data.Array
import Data.Char

main = do
  file <- readFile "test.txt"
  print (lines file)
  let ff = map ((!!) (lines file)) [1,3..(length (lines file) - 1)]
```

I think this code should wor fine (please correct me if not) but I get error:
The last statement in a do block must be an expression. Why I get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The do notation is a syntax sugar over monads. So your code when desugared will look like this:

```
readFile "test.txt" >>= \file ->
print (lines file) >> 
let ff = map ((!!) (lines file)) [1,3..(length (lines file) - 1)]
in ....
```

Now you can see that the expression isn't proper. You can learn more about this [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation).

A simple fix would be to just use `return ()`:

```
main = do
  file <- readFile "test.txt"
  print (lines file)
  let ff = map ((!!) (lines file)) [1,3..(length (lines file) - 1)]
  return ()
```

which will make the code typecheck:

```
readFile "test.txt" >>= \file ->
print (lines file) >> 
let ff = map ((!!) (lines file)) [1,3..(length (lines file) - 1)]
in return ()
```

But what you want probably is this:

```
main = do
  file <- readFile "test.txt"
  let ff = map ((!!) (lines file)) [1,3..(length (lines file) - 1)]
  print ff
```

Answer (score 0):

The (!!) suggested in the other answer is smelly.

```
everyOther :: [a] -> [a]
everyOther = catMaybes . zipWith ($) (cycle [const Nothing, Just])
```

Alternatively:

```
everyOther :: [a] -> [a]
everyOther (x:x':xs) = x : everyOther xs
everyOther _ = []
```